# One UITableViewController in multiple UIViewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to use one `UITableViewController` to multiple `UIViewControllers`. If yes how is it possible, Thanks in advance.

I have 3 screens`(UIViewControllers)` with same layout those are having `UITablewView`. So, can I create one `UITableViewController` for all those screens and can I use that in all the screens`(UIViewControllers)`. If yes please give me some idea and no need to use custom cells

Comment: You can use the same `UITableViewController` with different DataSource depending upon the data to be shown. If you want to use different cell, you can also do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply don't want implement same delegate and data source methods twice, do it in one controller and subclass others from it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to fullly understand what a `UITableViewController` actually is; it is infact a subclass of `UIViewController`.

Your `UIViewControllers` don't need a `UITableViewController`. If you wish to use `UIViewController` you should manually implement a `UITableView`.

Given that a tableView needs a set delegate and datasource, I think it may be a little complicated for you to reuse the same tableView with many ViewControllers. Unless you are happy to oursource this work to a seperate class or hotswap on display.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible , but you had to add uiitableview in all 3 viewcontrollers .

here is some example..!
[image]
set tag to that tableview as 21

[image]

and in tableview implementation file do your implementation like this

```
@implementation LCsampleTableView

        UITableView *tableView1;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    // self = [super init];
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {

        tableView1 =(UITableView *)[self viewWithTag:21];
        [tableView1 setDelegate:self];
        [tableView1 setDataSource:self];


        //     [self myviewDidload];

    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Table view start
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;

}




-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tblCell"];



    //cell = myCellDeque;
    if(cell == nil){
        //        cell = myCellDeque;

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"tblCell"];

        UILabel *lb1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 6, 154, 20)];
        lb1.tag = 1; // Set a constant for this
        lb1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.0];
        [lb1 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        lb1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                cell.contentView.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:7.0/255.0 green:91.0/255.0 blue:164.0/255.0 alpha:1]  ;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lb1];


    }


    return  cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {






}



#pragma -mark tableDelete

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {










}



@end
```

add this tableview with class in all three controllers then you dont had to code for this tableview in all 3 controllers. hope it helps

add tag to the tableview like this 
[image]

Comment: Where is the viewWithTag method and what should I do with viewWithTag method

Comment: note this LCsampleTableView class should be a subclass of uiview than you will get its method viewwithtag

Comment: I have a situation here after selecting a row I need to navigate to the another viewcontroller

Comment: in tableview did select delegate method you can do performsegue

Comment: for reference you can view this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478185/performing-segue-from-another-class

Comment: I'm sorry to say I'm not using the storyboard or nib files

Comment: you can add this view programmatically also . their is no big deal in that.

Comment: In didSelectMethod I have written this code BBSkillsViewController* skillsViewController = [[BBSkillsViewController alloc] init];
    [skillsViewController navigateToOtherViewController] in navigateToOtherViewController code is like this BBViewController* viewController = [[BBViewController alloc] init]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
 but its not working

Comment: problem is this line .....BBViewController* viewController = [[BBViewController alloc] init];

Comment: initiate viewcontroller like this ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540125/instantiating-a-view-controller-programmatically-with-storyboard-from-appdelegat